# Storing data from attendance system

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a students attendance system and when I'm attempting to store information to the database, I'm getting various errors about the attendance status. I'm aware this isn't a typical problem for all but it would help a beginner of PHP.

```
        <form action="tutor_attendance.php" method="post">

        <table class="table table-striped">
            <tr>
            <th>Student ID</th> <th>Module Name</th> <th>Attendance Status </th>
            </tr> 

            <?php $result=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM student");
            // $serialnumber=0;
            $counter=0;

            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
            {

            ?>

            <tr>
            <td> <?php echo $row['stud_id']; ?> </td>
            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['stud_id']; ?>" name="stud_id[]" >
            <td> <?php echo $row['module_1']; ?> </td>
            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['module_1']; ?>" name="module_1[]">

            <td>
            <input type="radio" name="attendance_status[<?php echo $counter; ?>]" value="Present">Present
            <input type="radio" name="attendance_status[<?php echo $counter; ?>]" value="Absent">Absent
            <input type="radio" name="attendance_status[<?php echo $counter; ?>]" value="Late">Late
            </td>
            </tr>

            <?php

            $counter++;
            }   

            ?>

        </table>

        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary " value="submit" >

        </form>
```

The code above is the form that I'm using to present data from the database and then capture their attendance with a radio button.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
foreach($_POST['attendance_status'] as $id->$attendance_status)
{
    $stud_id=$_POST['stud_id'][$id];
    $module_1=$_POST['module_name'][$id];
    $date=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT into attedance('stud_id, module_name, attendance_status, date) VALUES('$stud_id', '$module_1','$attendance_status','$date')");
}
}
```

Then the code above this is once the submit button has been pressed. The errors that I'm getting are: Undefined variable: attendance_status and Creating default object from empty value. Any help would be appreciated. The errors are occurring on line 8 - foreach($_POST['attendance_status'] as $id->$attendance_status)

Comment: You have an errant apostrophe

Comment: @Strawberry where abouts?

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to run queries in a loop. You should collect what needs to be inserted in the loop and have one insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a few different problems but the error you are getting is due to improper foreach syntax, which should be `key => value` not `key->value`

```
foreach($_POST['attendance_status'] as $id => $attendance_status) {
}
```

The errant quote in your SQL is not causing this error, but it is certainly another error. See this line:

```
"INSERT into attedance('stud_id, module_name, ...
```

Also did you really typo your table name for attendance?  My guess is that it should be:

```
"INSERT into attendance(stud_id, module_name, ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much! (and thank you for the obviously SQL error as well)